# MyUnifiedNativeAd.OnUnifiedNativeAdLoaded (Android.Gms.Ads.Formats.UnifiedNativeAd ad) crash on some devices _ Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, unifiednativeadview

My Xamarin.Android app crashes on some devices
Stacktrace says MyUnifiedNativeAd.OnUnifiedNativeAdLoaded (Android.Gms.Ads.Formats.UnifiedNativeAd ad)

Here is stacktrace

```
MyUnifiedNativeAd.OnUnifiedNativeAdLoaded (Android.Gms.Ads.Formats.UnifiedNativeAd ad)
UnifiedNativeAd+IOnUnifiedNativeAdLoadedListenerInvoker.n_OnUnifiedNativeAdLoaded_Lcom_google_android_gms_ads_formats_UnifiedNativeAd_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_ad)
(wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.26(intptr,intptr,intptr)
```

Here is my code where I do inflate and initializing of Listener

```
UnifiedNativeAdView adView = (UnifiedNativeAdView)LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ad_unified, null);
            FrameLayout frameLayout = inflated.FindViewById<FrameLayout>(Resource.Id.frameLayout1);
            var a = new MyUnifiedNativeAd(adView, frameLayout);
            AdLoader adLoader = new AdLoader.Builder(Context, Resources.GetString(Resource.String.ad_unit_id))
                .ForUnifiedNativeAd(a)
                .WithAdListener(new MyAdListener())
                .Build();
            adLoader.LoadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().Build());
```

This is listener Class which implements IOnUnifiedNativeAdLoadedListener interface

```
class MyUnifiedNativeAd : Java.Lang.Object, IOnUnifiedNativeAdLoadedListener
    {
        UnifiedNativeAdView AdView = null;
        FrameLayout frame = null;
        public MyUnifiedNativeAd( UnifiedNativeAdView adv, FrameLayout f)
        {
            AdView = adv;
            frame = f;
        }
        public void OnUnifiedNativeAdLoaded(UnifiedNativeAd ad)
        {
            if (ad is null)
                return;
            MediaView mv = AdView.FindViewById<MediaView>(Resource.Id.ad_media);
            TextView advertiser = AdView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.ad_advertiser);
            TextView headline = AdView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.ad_headline);
            ImageView img = AdView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.ad_app_icon);
            TextView body = AdView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.ad_body);
            RatingBar rating = AdView.FindViewById<RatingBar>(Resource.Id.ad_stars);
            TextView price = AdView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.ad_price);
            TextView store = AdView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.ad_store);
            Button action = AdView.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.ad_call_to_action);
            List<View> v = new List<View>() { mv, advertiser, headline, img, body, rating, price, store, action };
            action.Text = ad.CallToAction;
            store.Text = ad.Store;
            price.Text = ad.Price;
            rating.NumStars = ad.StarRating is null ? 0 : ad.StarRating.IntValue();
            body.Text = ad.Body;
            img.SetImageDrawable(ad.Icon.Drawable);
            headline.Text = ad.Headline;
            advertiser.Text = ad.Advertiser;
            AdView.MediaView = mv;
            AdView.SetNativeAd(ad);
            frame.RemoveAllViews();
            frame.AddView(AdView);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
Sometimes Google send us ad,which doesn't have icon.
If ad doesn't have icon, it means Icon property is null.
When I tried to set Icon to ImageView, it threw exception

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue 
I think so
After add "google_app_id" in the "string.xml" file with admob app id value, I tested many times and error was gone

Comment: No, problem is came back :(